# Writting $S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r_1+k+1)(r_2+k+1)(r_3+k+1)}$ as a rational function of $r_1,r_2$ and $r_3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I'll give an example of what I'm trying to say. Consider the equation, where $r_1>r_2>0$ and both integers:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r_1+k+1)(r_2+k+1)} = \frac{1}{r_1-r_2}\left(
\frac{1}{r_2+1}+ \frac{1}{r_2+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r_1} \tag{1}
\right)
\end{align}

I wanted something similar for
\begin{align}
S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r_1+k+1)(r_2+k+1)(r_3+k+1)} 
\end{align}

With $r_1>r_2>r_3>0$ and integers. Where $S$ is written as a simple rational function like $(1)$. This way we shall avoid anything written as digamma functions or harmonic series.

I'm not sure which tags to use for this question. If someone can provide more suitable ones it would be appreciated.

Comment: See my question, which provides an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980816/express-sum-n-1-infty-dfrac1-prod-k-1m-na-k-as-a-finite-sum

Answer (score 2):

Given any set of $n$ distinct positive numbers $r_1 > r_2 > \cdots > r_n > 0$, let $S_n(r_1,\cdots,r_n)$ be the sum

$$S_n(r_1,\ldots,r_n) = \sum_{s=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{r_k+s}$$

The sum we want is $S_3(r_1,r_2,r_3)$ and we already know the formula for $S_2(r_1,r_2)$ for integers.

In general, we can express $S_n$ in terms of $S_{n-1}$. For any $n \ge 3$, we have

$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{r_k +s}
&= \frac{1}{r_1+s}\frac{1}{r_n+s} \prod_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{r_k+s}\\
&= \frac{1}{r_n-r_1}\left(\frac{1}{r_1+s} - \frac{1}{r_n+s}\right)
\prod_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{r_k+s} \\
&= \frac{1}{r_n-r_1}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{r_k+s} - \prod_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{r_k+s}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Summing over $s$ leads to

$$S_n(r_1,\ldots,r_n) = \frac{1}{r_n - r_1}[ S_{n-1}(r_1\ldots,r_{n-1}) - S_{n-1}(r_2,\ldots,r_n)]\tag{*1}$$
In particular, for $n = 3$, we have

$$S_3(r_1,r_2,r_3) = \frac{1}{r_3-r_1}\left[S_2(r_1,r_2) - S_2(r_2,r_3)\right]$$

For integers $r_1, r_2, r_3$, you can use this identity and the known formula for $S_2(r_1,r_2)$ and $S_2(r_2,r_3)$ to derive the closed form you want.

For general $n > 3$, we can repeatedly apply $(*1)$ and express $S_n(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ as a linear combination of $S_2(r_1,r_2)$, $S_2(r_2,r_3), \ldots, S_2(r_{n-1},r_n)$ with rational functions in $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ as coefficients.

To derive the linear combination, let $P(s) = \prod_{k=1}^n (r_k + s)$. Since all $r_k$ are distinct, it has following partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{P(s)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\alpha_k}{r_k + s}\quad\text{ where }\quad \alpha_k = \frac{1}{P'(-r_k)}$$

As long as $n > 1$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k = \lim_{s\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k s}{r_k+s} = \lim_{s\to\infty} \frac{s}{P(s)} = 0$$
This allow us to rewrite $\frac{1}{P(s)}$ as

$$\frac{1}{P(s)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k\left(\frac{1}{r_k+s} - \frac{1}{s}\right)$$

Summing over $s$ give us

$$S_n(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n) = \sum_{s=1}^\infty \frac{1}{P(s)} =
\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k S_1(r_k)\tag{*2}$$

where $S_1(r) = \sum\limits_{s=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{r+s} - \frac{1}{s}\right)
= -\gamma - \psi(r+1)$ and $\psi(r)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

In particular for $n = 2$, we obtain

$$S_2(r_1,r_2) = \frac{1}{r_2-r_1}\left(S_1(r_1) - S_1(r_2)\right)
= \frac{1}{r_1-r_2}\left(\psi(r_1+1)-\psi(r_2+1)\right)
$$

With this choice of $S_1(r)$, $(*1)$ is also true for $n=2$. For intergers $r_1,r_2$, this reduces to the formula we already know

$$S_2(r_1,r_2) = \frac{1}{r_1-r_2} \sum_{r=r_2+1}^{r_1} \frac{1}{r}\tag{*3}$$

Let $A_k = \sum\limits_{j=1}^k \alpha_j$, we can rewrite $(*2)$ as
$$\begin{align}
S_n(r_1,\ldots,r_n) &= A_1 S_1(r_1) + \sum_{k=2}^n ( A_k - A_{k-1} )S_1(r_k)\\
&= A_n S_1(r_n) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} A_k (S_1(r_k) - S_1(r_{k+1}))\\
\end{align}
$$

Since $A_n = 0$, we obtain following decomposition of $S_n(\cdots)$:

$$S_n(r_1,\ldots,r_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} B_k S_2(r_k,r_{k+1})
\quad\text{ where }\quad
B_k = (r_{k+1}-r_k)\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{P'(-r_j)}$$

As an example, when $n = 3$

$$\begin{align}
B_1 &= (r_2-r_1)\frac{1}{P'(-r_1)} = \frac{1}{r_3 - r_1}\\
B_2 &= (r_3-r_2)\left(\frac{1}{P'(-r_1)} + \frac{1}{P'(-r_2)}\right) = \frac{1}{r_1-r_3}
\end{align}$$
For integers $r_1 > r_2 > r_3 > 0$, we can use $(*3)$ to deduce

$$S_3(r_1,r_2,r_3) = -\frac{1}{r_1-r_3}\left[\frac{1}{r_1-r_2}\sum_{r=r_2+1}^{r_1} \frac{1}{r}
- \frac{1}{r_2-r_3}\sum_{r=r_3+1}^{r_2}\frac1r\right]$$

For general $n$ and integers $r_1 > r_2 > \cdots > r_n > 0$, the corresponding formula is

$$S_n(r_1,\ldots,r_n) = -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^k\prod_{i=1,\ne j}^{n}\frac{1}{r_i-r_j}\right)\sum_{r=r_{k+1}+1}^{r_k} \frac{1}{r}\right]$$

Comment: I think the upper limit of the inner product should be $n$.

Comment: @martycohen yes, that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wolfy,

$\frac1{(a + k) (b + k) (c + k)}
=-\frac1{(a - b) (b - c) (b + k)} - \frac1{(c-a) (b-c) (c + k)} - \frac1{(a - b) (c - a) (a + k)}
$.

You can use this
to split your sum
into 3 sums of a
single reciprocal.

The generalization to
an arbitrary number of terms
seems somewhat evident,
but I am too lazy right now
to work out the details.
Probably something like

$\dfrac1{\prod_{j=1}^m (a_j+k)}
=\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{(-1)^{\text{something like }j}}{(a_j+k)\prod_{i=1, i\ne j}^m(a_i-a_j)}
$.

As is evident,
I'm not sure
what the sign 
of the expressions should be.

Comment: But, after this split the right member still depends on k am I understand well ? I guess Pinteco was asking for a closed form ?

Comment: Right. You get 3 sums on k. Depending on the $a_j$ (or $r_j$), there might be cancellation.