# Express $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^m (n+a_k)} $ as a finite sum.

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

This is a generalization
(and answer to)
[Writting $S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r_1+k+1)(r_2+k+1)(r_3+k+1)}$ as a rational function of $r_1,r_2$ and $r_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979940/writting-s-sum-k-0-infty-frac1r-1k1r-2k1r-3k1-as-a-ra/2979973?noredirect=1#comment6150478_2979973).

Let
$S
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^m (n+a_k)}
$
where $m \ge 2$ and the $a_k$
are positive integers.

Find an expression
for $S$ involving only finite sums.

I get
$S
=-\sum_{k=1}^mc_kH_{a_k}
$
where
$c_k=
\dfrac1{\prod_{j=1, j\ne k}^m (a_j-a_k)}
$
and
$H_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac1{j}$.

It is interesting that
a quite good approximation to $S$ is
$-\sum_{k=1}^mc_k\ln(a_k)
$.

Comment: Do you mean that $a_k$ are *distinct* positive integers?

Comment: Yes I do. 6 more

Answer (score 1):

Provided that $\text{Re}(a),\text{Re}(b)>0$ we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b},\tag{1} $$
hence by partial fraction decomposition, assuming $\text{Re}(c)>0$,

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)(n+c)}&=&\frac{1}{c-a}\left[\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}-\frac{\psi(b)-\psi(c)}{b-c}\right]\\&=&\frac{(c-b)\psi(a)+(a-c)\psi(b)+(a-b)\psi(c)}{(a-c)(a-b)(b-c)}\end{eqnarray*}\tag{2} $$
with $\psi(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\log\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=H_{z-1}-\gamma$.
 If more variables are involved the approach is just the same.

Comment: I am looking for an explicit formula in terms of the $a_k$. I am aware of the discussion in places such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula, but would like it made explicit.

Comment: @martycohen: I do not understand your request. $(2)$ gives an explicit relation between the given series and $H_{a_1},\ldots,H_{a_n}$. Only finite sums are involved.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: I want an explicit formula for arbitrary $m$.

Comment: @martycohen: you already have one, $$ -\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{H_{a_k}}{\prod_{j\neq k}(a_j-a_k)}.$$

Comment: I was hoping for one similar in form to your equation (2). Maybe I could modify mine so the denominator is $\prod_{1 \le j < k \le m}(a_j-a_k)$.